# pandas read rotated csv files

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any function in pandas that can **directly load** a rotated csv file?

Of corse we can get around this problem using some data wangling techniques like `transpose` and `slicing`. I am wondering there should be a quick way in API?

To be specific, the header information in the first col instead of the first row.
For example:

```
A 1 2
B 3 5
C 6 7
```

and I would like the **loaded** `DataFrame` this way

```
A B C
1 3 5
2 5 7
```

Comment: I don't believe the `read_csv` api suuports what you are asking, I would read the csv and just call `.T()` like CT Zhu has suggested

Answer (score 0):

Use `.T()`:

```
>>> print df
   0  1  2
0  A  1  2
1  B  3  5
2  C  6  7

[3 rows x 3 columns]
>>> print df.T
   0  1  2
0  A  B  C
1  1  3  6
2  2  5  7

[3 rows x 3 columns]
>>>
```